# Java Spring PagingAndSortingRepository exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, pagination

I am struggling to find a list of jpa-s in my Spring web app by using the PagingAndSortingRepository but i always get some kind of an exception.
(my userRepository extends JpaRepository which extends PagingAndSortingRepository)

This is my code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class UsersController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/view-u", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(com.myapp.util.Um.Privileges).CAN_USER_READ)")
    public @ResponseBody List<JsonUser> getUsersPaginated(){
        List<JsonUser> result = new ArrayList<JsonUser>();

        result.addAll(dashboardServiceImpl.findUsersPaginatedAndSorted());

        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

and service :

```
@Service
public class DasboardServiceImpl implements DashboardService /*My interface*/{

    ...
    @Override
    public List<JsonUser> findUsersPaginatedAndSorted(){
        List<JsonUser> modelList = new ArrayList<JsonUser>();

        final List<UserJPA> jpaList = userRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "username")).getContent();

        for(final UserJPA jpa : jpaList){
            modelList.add(new JsonUser(jpa));
        }

        return modelList;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. It throws the exception :

> Unknown name value [] for enum class [com.health.common.enums.Gender];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name
>   value [] for enum class [com.health.common.enums.Gender]

I attest that the Gender enum works perfectly in every other database communication.

I then tried doing this to the service method :

```
    @Override
    public List<JsonUser> findUsersPaginatedAndSorted(){
        List<JsonUser> modelList = new ArrayList<JsonUser>();

        try{
            // First call -> enum exception
            userRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "username"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\n\t"+e.getMessage()+"\n");
        }

        // Second call - collection exception
        final List<UserJPA> jpaList = userRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "username")).getContent();

        for(final UserJPA jpa : jpaList){
            modelList.add(new JsonUser(jpa));
        }

        return modelList;
    }
```

And this time, i get a different exception on the second findAll call :

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: collection is not
>   associated with any session; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with
>   any session

After a lot of digging and frustration, i found the only solution which works for me :
I add @Transactional(readOnly=true) to the service method and catch different exceptions in both service and controller :

controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class UsersController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/view-u", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(com.health.common.util.Um.Privileges).CAN_USER_READ)")
    public @ResponseBody List<JsonUser> getUsersPaginated(){
        List<JsonUser> result = new ArrayList<JsonUser>();
        // i have no idea why
        try{
            // when called the first time, it throws "Transaction marked as rollbackOnly"
            result.addAll(dashboardServiceImpl.findUsersPaginatedAndSorted());
        }catch(Exception e){
            // and when called the second time, it works
            result.addAll(dashboardServiceImpl.findUsersPaginatedAndSorted());
        }

        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

( Notice the exception i'm getting on the first service method call is :

> TransactionSystemException :  Could not commit JPA transaction; nested
>   exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked
>   as rollbackOnly
>   )

And service :

```
@Service
public class DasboardServiceImpl implements DashboardService{

    ...
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<JsonUser> findUsersPaginatedAndSorted(){
        List<JsonUser> modelList = new ArrayList<JsonUser>();

        // I have no idea why
        try{
            // when called the first time it throws (GenderEnum) exception
            userRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "username"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\n\t"+e.getMessage()+"\n");
        }

        // and when called the second time, it works
        final List<UserJPA> jpaList = userRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "username")).getContent();

        for(final UserJPA jpa : jpaList){
            modelList.add(new JsonUser(jpa));
        }

        return modelList;
    }
}
```

As i said, this works for me and i get a proper list of users, but this solution is far from elegant. Notice that i am doing a double call of both service method and of repository method. :(

How can i fix my code so i don't have to do these double calls ?

Why doesn't my original solution work ? Why does findAll(Paginated) requires @Transactional when it is a query that doesn't alter the database ?

Sorry for the long post and thank you in advance.

Comment: can you execute this query in DB: select * from [user-table] where [gender-column] is null

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly. I can also execute all other controller functions for working with a single user with no trouble regardless of the gender.

Comment: Yes, but I meant do you have null gender users

Comment: Yes. I have 4 of those.

Comment: Unknown name value in first exception occurs after sql execution so repository did its job but parsing the entities failed while constructing gender probably in source it is calling Gender.valueOf(); method. Maybe not the reason but I would give a shot by fixing genders in DB. simply search anything in db which is i.e. not M and not F

Comment: I tried this query :

Comment: SELECT * FROM india_health.user where gender <> 'M' and gender <> 'F' and gender is not null;

Comment: But there are no records like that.

Comment: no need to "and gender is not null" you want to catch simply not M or not F doesnt matter null or not also make sure your gender enum values are M and F (i.e. male, female, Male, Female or local language)

Comment: It seems that these exceptions are happening in local. When i upload this to the server, everything works fine. I don't know why, but I'll manage to live with it. Sorry for bothering you with this needlessly.